# Using a varchar2 value for a column name during update

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried looking around but no luck. My problem is as follows:

I have a procedure that is given as input a column name and a column value. These are to be used to update a record in a table.

The following update statement is what I'm trying to implement:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE SET p_i_column_name = p_i_column_value WHERE ID = p_i_id;
```

Of course I know that this is incorrect but I wonder if there exists a way to let an update statement know which column to update via a varchar2 value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE example_table ' || 
                      ' SET ' || p_i_column_name || ' = :1 ' ||
                    ' WHERE id = :2'
    USING p_i_column_value, p_i_id;
END;
```

Be aware, however, that using dynamic SQL generally involves substantial increases in the complexity of your code and substantial decreases in its supportability.  You're transforming compile-time errors into run-time errors, for example, you can't track dependencies automatically, you generally need to log the SQL statements that are being executed somewhere in order to track down bugs, etc.  If you don't know at compile time what column you're updating, it seems highly likely that you would be better served by revising your data model.

Comment: I have no choice, since i have to do this to a large amount of columns where they update at various points in time per record. Also, Thanks for pointing out some of the cons. I try to log every possible update/insert on this procedure with its parameters so this would work out for me.